# How to remove cookie param in request header for a post request in angular 6

Tags: angular6, angular-http-interceptors, request-headers

When sending a post request cookie param is getting set in request header.
Is there any way to **stop sending cookie param in api request header** for a particular api call in angular interceptor

Answer (score 0):

`http module` by default does not set the cookie params. When you get the response, http module discards the cookie and does not add it in the follow up requests. So you have add it manually:

```
checkAuth() {
    // if we did not add { withCredentials: true }, response would be false because, cookies wont be attached
    return this.http.get<SignedinResponse>(this.rootUrl + '/signedin',{withCredentials:true}).pipe(
      tap(({ authenticated }) => {
        // console.log('response from /signedin', res);
        
      })
    );
  }
```

You have to add `{withCredentials:true}` this to each request manually. Instead we write interceptor, to modify the req obj and add the cookie by default.